# Angularjs application when profiled shows 63% of the time required to render the page as idle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, profiler

Issue:

My angularjs application page takes around 30 seconds to render the page.
When i run the google chrome profiler I could see 62% of the time required to render the page is taken by a fuction called '(idle)'.

Any clue what is happening ?

why is the page idle ..it should be rendering the page ...not just sit idle

[image]

Comment: "(idle)" is not a function - it just means that the page is idle

Comment: why is the page idle ..it should be rendering the page ...not just sit idle.

Comment: did you consider google...and read up on the topic?

Comment: yes, but couldnt find any useful information...i think its something to do with the way in which angularjs is doing

Comment: you couldn't possibly have done much to look for it...I just did several searches and found lots of information ... try a little harder

Answer (score 1):

The profiler is showing you CPU time, not wall-clock time.

That means it's blind to I/O.

Page-rendering requires I/O.
While the CPU is waiting for I/O to complete, it either has to find other things to do, or be idle.

BTW, I/O time is just CPU time, but on a different CPU.

BTW2, You've got it sorted on "Self" time.
You should sort on "Total" time, which appears to be inclusive of callees.
"Self" time is useless.
Why? Because if it is large, inclusive time shows it, and if it is small, it could still be wasting lots of time, just doing it by calling subroutines, which inclusive time shows.